# AngularJS - Directive's class name cannot bring into inner template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to make a directive which take a class name conditionally. However, I found that my code can work only if I hardcode the class name into the class attribute. If I try to use it with any expression, its failed to work.

For e.g.

```
// HTML

// Doesn't work (cannot find class="editable" in the final output template)
<tit-txt ng-class="true ? 'editable' : ''" ng-model="mdEnt.phone"></tit-txt>

// Works! (I can find class="editable" in the final output template)
<tit-txt class="editable" ng-model="mdEnt.phone"></tit-txt>
```

---

```
//JS

.directive('titTxt', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.editable = element.hasClass('editable') ? 'editable' : '';
        },
        template: '<input ng-class="editable" ng-model="ngModel" />',
    };
})
```

Anyone can explain to me that why is it happening? How can I use it with expression?

---

**UPDATE 1**

```
// HTML

// Doesn't work
<tit-txt ng-class="{'editable': true}" ng-model="mdEnt.phone"></tit-txt>
```

---

```
//JS

.directive('titTxt', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            fieldName: '@',
            ngModel: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element.hasClass('editable'));
            scope.editable = element.hasClass('editable') ? 'editable' : '';
        },
        template: '<div><span>{{title}}: </span><input id="{{fieldName}}" ng-class="{editable: true}" name="{{fieldName}}" ng-model="ngModel" /></div>',
    };
})
```

Anyone can explain to me that why I get **false** in the `console.log(element.hasClass('editable'));`?

Comment: Syntax for `ng-class` is `"{<class>: condition}"`

Comment: You need to do this: `ng-class="{'editable': true}"`

Comment: @AdnanUmer Thanks for your solution. Seems it is working now. But I have another question: Why I cannot make it work with   `<tit-txt class="{{'editable'}}" ng-model="mdEnt.phone"></tit-txt>`

Answer (score 0):

With the `class` attribute, the element's class is set by JavaScript. With the [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive, the class is set by the AngularJS framework. When there are more that one directive on an element, there is no guarantee of the order of execution of the code of the respective directives.

Avoid having AngularJS manipulate the DOM and having subsequent AngularJS manipulate the model based on the state of the DOM. With MVC frameworks the Model should be the [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) and the DOM should be directly determined by the Model.

```
<tit-txt inner-class="true ? 'editable' : ''" my-model="mdEnt.phone">
</tit-txt>
```

```
app.directive('titTxt', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            fieldName: '@',
            innerClass: '<',
            myModel: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.innerClass, function(newValue) {
                console.log("inner-class=", newValue);
            });
        },
        template: `<div><span>{{title}}: </span>
                      <input id="{{fieldName}}" ng-class="innerClass"
                             name="{{fieldName}}" ng-model="myModel" />
                   </div>`,
    };
})
```

Notice how the directive uses [one-way, `'<'`, binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) to compute the value of the `inner-class` attribute from an [AngularJS Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Also notice that I changed `ng-model` to `my-model`. The `ng-` prefix is reserved for core AngularJS directives. Use of `ng-model` should be specifically be avoided unless the [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) properly integrates with the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).