# AngularJS - Why I cannot get element class name in directive's link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got below code. I expect it will show me **true**. However, it show me false.

Can anyone explain it to me and provide me a solution to check if the class existed in the element? Thanks in advance.

```
// HTML
<tit-txt class="{{editable}}" ng-model="mdEnt.phone"></tit-txt>

//JS
.directive('titTxt', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element.hasClass('editable'));
        },
        template: '<input ng-model="ngModel" />',
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this:

```
// HTML
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <tit-txt custom-class="customClass" 
          cust-var="myVal"></tit-txt>
          <div ng-bind="myVal"></div>
</div>

//JS
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.customClass = "editable";
  $scope.myVal = "this";
});

app.directive('titTxt', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            customClass: '=',
            custVar: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope);
            console.log((scope.customClass === "editable"));
        },
        template: '<input class="myClass" ng-Model="custVar"/>',
    };
})
```

EDIT: Edited the code to include the working code. Here is the link for [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mYfJlC8Juj6hI5jQfIjr?p=preview)

Comment: I have tried your solution. Seems it is not work for me.

Comment: I have edited the code. Please check and see if this works for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a watcher to detect when the class is updated:

```
app.directive('titTxt', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myModel: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(hasClassEditable, function() {
                console.log(element.hasClass('editable'));
            });

            function hasClassEditable() {
                return element.hasClass('editable');
            }
        },
        template: '<input ng-model="myModel" />',
    };
})
```

Interpolated bindings such as `class={{editable}}` update each digest cycle. The directive needs to wait for a binding to update before using the value.

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/2VTafFe4I7x3uElxgjfv?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.run(function($rootScope,$timeout) {
  $rootScope.$timeout = $timeout;
})
.directive('titTxt', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myModel: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(hasClassEditable, function(value) {
                console.log("has class 'editable'", value);
            });

            function hasClassEditable() {
                return element.hasClass('editable');
            }
        },
        template: '<input ng-model="myModel" />',
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="editable" ng-change="$timeout()"
           ng-true-value="'editable'" ng-false-value="''" />
        add class "editable"
    <br>
    <tit-txt class="{{editable}}" my-model="inputTxt"></tit-txt>
    <br>
    editable="{{editable}}"
    <br>
    inputTxt="{{inputTxt}}"
    
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand what you said for interpolated bindings. However, is it means that I can skip the watcher if I do it with `<tit-txt ng-class="{'editable': true}" ng-model="mdEnt.phone"></tit-txt>`?   If I call the directive in `ng-class` way, that means I am not using interpolated bindings as I didn't use double curly brace.

Comment: Under-the-hood the [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive uses a watcher to evaluate the AngularJS Expresion and update the class  of the element appropriately.  It is going to have the same issues as interpolative binding with respect to timing.

Comment: May I know if `{'editable': true}` a type of interpolative binding?

Comment: To see how to avoid using `ng-class` and to directly compute an attribute with an AngularJS Expression, see [AngularJS - Directive's class name cannot bring into inner template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46328062/5535245).

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
  console.log(angular.element(element).hasClass('editable'));
}
```

Comment: If you console.log(element) what does it give you?

Comment: I get false. Seems that when I try to execute `.hasClass('editable')`. AngularJS is not yet added the `editable` class in dom.

Comment: Updated, added fourth arg to link() see if that has any change.

Answer (score -1):

Try with pre function,

```
        link: {
                    pre: function(scope, element, attr, controllers) {
                        console.log(element.hasClass('editable'));
                    },
                    post: function(scope, element, attr, controllers) {

                    },
       }
```